The number of primes between $N$ and $N^2$
An estimate for the number of primes between $N$ and $N^2$
is approximately
$${N^2} \cdot \prod\limits_{p \le N} {\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)}  \approx \pi \left( {{N^2}} \right) - \pi \left( N \right) 
$$
I presume that the following will always be true :
$${N^2} \cdot \prod\limits_{p \le N} {\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)}  > \pi \left( {{N^2}} \right) - \pi \left( N \right)
$$
Is it possible to prove this ?

I'm not clear on why you think that an estimate for the number of primes in that range is presumably also an upper bound for that number.

If $S_N$ is the set of primes $\leq N,$ then $$\pi(N^2)-\pi(N)=\sum_{T\subseteq S_n}(-1)^{|T|}\left\lfloor\frac{N^2}{\prod _{p\in T}p}\right\rfloor$$ Not sure if that helps. It seems like there is no reason for the total fractional parts for when $|T|$ even would be less than the total fractional parts when $|T|$ is odd, which determines the  sign of the difference difference between $\pi(N^2)-\pi(N).$ and the peoduct.

The formula above is an inclusion-exclusion count for the number of numbers from $1$ to $N^2$ which are not divisible by any prime in $S_{N}.$ Well, you probably need to subtract $1$, since it counts $1$ as well as the primes from $N+1$ to $N^2.$

So, $$N^2\prod_{p\leq N}(1-1/p) -(\pi(N^2)-\pi(N))=1+\sum_{T\subseteq S_N}(-1)^{|T|}\left{\frac{N^2}{\prod_{p\in T}p}\right},$$
where ${x}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the fractional part function. The $1+$ makes it more likely to be positive, but the rational part function will return something like a uniform random variable from $[0,1].$  It's not clear why this would always be positive. Other than the $+1,$ there are an equal number of positive and negative terms on the right side.

With a python program, I get that this is not true for $N=13,14,17.$

$\pi(169)-\pi(13)=33,$ and the product is $$\frac{13^2\cdot12\cdot10\cdot6\cdot 4\cdot 2}{13\cdot11\cdot7\cdot5\cdot3\cdot2}=\approx 32.4.$$

I suspect the density of such $N$ is $1/2.$ But I don't see a wat to prove that.

I think the premise of the comparison is wrong. The prime number theorem says that $\pi(N^2) - \pi(N) \sim N^2/\log(N^2) - N/\log N \sim \frac12N^2/\log N$. However, by Mertens's theorems,
$$
N^2 \prod_{p\le N} \biggl( 1-\frac1p \biggr) \sim  \frac{N^2}{e^\gamma\log N},
$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. In particular, $e^\gamma \approx 1.781 < 2$, so the inequality in the OP will certainly hold for all sufficiently large $N$, but only because it's not a good approximation to begin with.

This is what I hoped for. Is it possible to find the sufficiently large N for which the inequality will hold for all N_1, where N_1>N ?

The much-cited paper of Rosser and Schoenfeld should contain explicit estimates that will serve that purpose.

This is not true for $N=13, 14,$ or $17.$
$\pi(169)-\pi(13)=33,$ and the product is $$13^2\cdot\frac{12\cdot10\cdot6\cdot 4\cdot 2}{13\cdot11\cdot7\cdot5\cdot3\cdot2}=\approx 32.4.$$
I found this example by writing a Python script.
In fact, between 18 and 100, inclusive, there are only five values where you conjecture is true.
That means my earlier conjecture that the density is 1/2 seems wrong.
